# Why do superscripts for \det behave differently?

Tags: pdftex, math-operators

The built-in command `\det` simply prints 'det' in roman style. However, a superscript in display math (e.g. `\[\det^N\]`) appears directly above and centered, rather than at the top-right corner. I've never seen this behavior for any other type of superscript.

Why does `\det` have this special behavior, and how can I turn it off?

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[\det^2\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\det\nolimits^2`

Comment: Or code `\det{}^2`.

Comment: I'm not sure why Knuth defined `\det` to take limits like `\lim` or `\sum` in display math; LaTeX followed suit. On the other hand, I've never seen `\det^{N}`: what should it mean?

Comment: @egreg Like $\sin^n(x)$, I wanted to use it as a shorthand for $\det(\text{very long expression})^N$. Otherwise, it's easy for the $N$ to get lost.

Comment: I don't think your readers will understand. Anyway, use `\det\nolimits^{N}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `latex.ltx`:

```
\def\log{\mathop{\operator@font log}\nolimits}
\def\lim{\mathop{\operator@font lim}}
\def\det{\mathop{\operator@font det}}
```

`\det` is defined in the same manner as `\lim`, but you want the behavior of `\log`. This can be achieved by appending `\nolimits` to the definition of `\det`, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\[ \log_0^1 \textstyle \log_0^1 \]
\[ \lim_0^1 \textstyle \lim_0^1 \]
\[ \det_0^1 \textstyle \det_0^1 \]

\apptocmd{\det}{\nolimits}{}{\errmessage{Could not patch \string\det.}}

\[ \det_0^1 \textstyle \det_0^1 \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Package `amsmath`

Package `amsmath` follows defines the commands in the following way:

```
\def\det{\qopname\relax m{det}}
\def\lim{\qopname\relax m{lim}}
\def\log{\qopname\relax o{log}}
```

Thus, `\det` can be redfined:

```
documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ \log_0^1 \textstyle \log_0^1 \]
\[ \lim_0^1 \textstyle \lim_0^1 \]
\[ \det_0^1 \textstyle \det_0^1 \]

\renewcommand*{\det}{\qopname\relax o{det}}

\[ \det_0^1 \textstyle \det_0^1 \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result amsmath]

The official way is using `\DeclareMathOperator`. It is limited to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\det\relax % "Undefine" \det
\DeclareMathOperator{\det}{det}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the "official way" of changing the definition of `\det`. :-)